# Unreal Engine is not opening after first installation

Tags: runtime-error, unreal-engine5

After installing Unreal Engine and launching it, I got this error message:

```
A Unreal Engine Process Has Crashed: UE-

Unhandled Exception: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION reading address 0x00000000000013c0

UnrealEditor_D3D12RHI
UnrealEditor_D3D12RHI
UnrealEditor_D3D12RHI
UnrealEditor_D3D12RHI
UnrealEditor_D3D12RHI
UnrealEditor_D3D12RHI
UnrealEditor_RHI
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
kernel32
ntdll
```

I am new to Unreal Engine and I don't have any idea what this means (though I have experience with website development). I tried looking up answers, but without any luck. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Looks like something is up with DirectX12. Can you install the debugging symbols for Unreal and try again? Because this list would be more helpfull with actual filenames and line numbers. Also, do you have the newest graphics driver and compatible hardware for DirectX12?

Comment: @MaxPlay I installed the Debugging Symbols and found this error in the script: Shader Model 6.6 atomic64 is not supported
Device->CreateCommandSignature(&CommandSignatureDesc, nullptr, IID_PPV_ARGS(DispatchIndirectComputeCommandSignature.GetInitReference())) failed 
 at D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\D3D12RHI\Private\Windows\WindowsD3D12Device.cpp:1763 
 with error DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED

Comment: Could you edit your question to make ther error more readable and also, if you can reproduce the crash, update your stack trace?

Comment: On Windows, presumably? What edition and version? What version of Unreal Engine? Please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75527210/edit), not here in comments (*** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

So from this much information we cannot give you a solution that you desire. But you can increase the way of Logging of Unreal Engine.
Please go to the

- Epic launcher -> Unreal Engine -> Library
- Click the dropdown arrow
- Select options
- Check "Editor symbols for debugging"

In this way, Unreal Engine will give you more clue about the error. This is the all answer you can get for now. If you edit your question, I will for sure extend my answer.